# google chrome background page suggestions/help

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I use a background page, to highlight a certain keyword on a website, no matter the website (google chrome extension)? No pop ups or anything, it just edits a keyword, on a site someone is viewing. I've seen it done before, I just can't figure out how! Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know how to highlight keywords in javascript? What do you mean by "it just edits a keyword"? How do you set a keyword?

Comment: sorry, by keyword I meant I want to make an extension that highlights a certain word (for example food) on every page the person visits. I was curious as how to do this, do I use a background page? or what.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use [jQuery highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) from a content script:

```
"content_scripts": [
 {
   "matches": ["http://*/*"],
   "js": ["jquery.js", "jquery.highlight-3.js", "myscript.js"]
 }
],
```

So you would include jquery, the plugin and your code that controls it into every page.